# Почему не работает javascript?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Есть задание :
Выбрать все ссылки, сделать чтобы они мигали. То есть 1 секунду все красные, следующую 1 секунду – они зеленые, в следующую – снова красные и так далее.
Реализовал вот так:

```
var c="red";
function select_radio() {
   if (c == "red") {
    c="green";
   } else c="red";

   var elements = $('a');
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements.get(i).style.color = c;

   }
   setTimeout("select_radio()",100);
 }
```

Так все работает.
Но почему не работает вот так:

```
var c="red";
function select_radio() {
   if (c == "red") {
    c="green";
   } 
   if (c == "green") {
    c="red";
   }

   var elements = $('a');
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements.get(i).style.color = c;

   }
   setTimeout("select_radio()",100);
 }
```

Ногами не пинайте)))) Не врубаюсь, может сказывается что я болею?((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде смотрите что происходит:

```
   if (c == "red") {
    c="green";
   } 
   if (c == "green") {
    c="red";
   }
```

если с == red он становится green и следующей строкой он сравнивается с green и опять становится red. т.е. он у вас всегда red, в первом примере вы используете ELSE - и всё работает верно и как нужно. Думаю второй пример можно наладить если вместо второго условия `IF` использовать `ELSE IF`. Примерно как [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp), в третьем примере.

По этой строчке

```
var elements = $('a');
```

понял что у вас jQuery, зачем вы используете такие конструкции как:

```
elements.get(i).style.color = c;
```

Есть же: [each](http://jquery-docs.ru/Utilities/jQuery.each/), [css](http://jquery-docs.ru/CSS/css/#namevalue), [eq](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/eq/)

Да и вашу задачу я бы решил так:

```
setInterval(function(){ $('a').css('color','green'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ setInterval(function(){ $('a').css('color','red'); }, 2000); }, 1000);
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/zYbW4/